# Trouble migrating ubuntu installation from an old PC into a less old Notebook - boot volume not detected

Tags: boot, migration

I've had Ubuntu running on an old PC for a while (Core2Duo and [Asus P5Q Pro](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q_PRO/specifications/) motherboard). The PCs power supply is dead and I wanted to migrate the system to an unused [HP EliteBook 8570p](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03393945) laptop.

When I try to boot I get greeted by an Intel Boot Agent message and on the next screen it says

> Boot Device not found

An Ubuntu installation usb stick boots fine, I have also managed to install Ubuntu from this stick on a spare hard drive and it boots fine.

Since the Ubuntu of the old system contains tons of configuration which would take a significant amount of time to redo I'd really like to just get that drive booted. I'm hoping somebody would be able to help me out what the problem is and how I could solve this.

thanks!

Comment: Personally I'd format the elitebook (a device I don't know) as I wanted (ie. I'd probably create a /home separate partition but this is optional) and then copy data there (most data is in /home, though your software may have it other places as well).  Then I would install fresh using 'something-else' & select the already created partition(s) ensuring I had 'format' checkbox un-ticked. It will note software added (none if you only copy /home, but will be some if you copy all), erase system directories, install, add back added software & ask to reboot. Your settings will be there (as in /home)

Comment: Your old disk is your backup, and it gives you a 'fresh' (or at least '*freshish*' system).  It's not exactly what you're asking for, but it's what I'd do.

Comment: I appreciate your input, however i am afraid it is not as simple as you suggest. Having booted from the usb-install drive i can read both other partitions (the fresh install and the old install) but I cannot write to any of those, and especially permissions cannot be determined. 

my linux skills are rusty to say the least. I am worried that all I would do is mess up permissions and loose more time than I gain. I'd really prefer a solution to my original question.

Comment: The method I provided is less error-prone, and in my opinion far simpler requiring lower posix knowledge due to it all being data copy from old to new drive and a new install & handled by the installer (which will see the data, and install around it if options as I suggested are used). Of course you're welcome to way for other 'answers'.

Comment: I tried and it wont copy the home folder due to expected permission issues. The idea is simple I agree.

Comment: really nobody has any idea here?

Comment: I can't imagine any permission problems, unless you did something wrongly...  We cannot see what you actually did (commands), and the specific error that was returned (your actual command used is key to understanding the permissions issue) so cannot help with vague things like '*permissions issues*'. Was the fs mounted RW?  Was your $UID the same as that which created the directory? or did you elevate your privileges? etc.  Without specifics we'd be listing hundreds of possibilities....

Answer (score 0):

Press the Power button and press F10 key repeatedly to enter teh BIOS setup menu. (depending on different manufacturer, instead of F10, it's maybe ESC, F1, F2, F8...)
2) On the BIOS Setup screen, press F9 to select and load the BIOS Setup Default settings.
3) Press F10 to Save and Exit.
4) Use the arrow keys to select Yes, then press Enter when asked Exit Saving Changes?
5) Follow the prompts to restart your computer.

Comment: Hey thanks!
I've actually tried that first and does not change the situation. Also tried changing boot mode from Legacy to UEFI. 

If I swap the drive with the fresh ubuntu installation it boots fine without the intel boot agent even showing up, which kind of suggests the problem is not the bios setting.